# How to tell if an AIX machine is running on a power7 cpu?

Tags: aix, powerpc

I know how to query the cpu type in C code using the sys/systemcfg.h __power_7() macro.  Is there a handy command that also provides this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "lsattr -El proc0":

```
# lsattr -El proc0
frequency   3220000000     Processor Speed       False
smt_enabled true           Processor SMT enabled False
smt_threads 4              Processor SMT threads False
state       enable         Processor state       False
type        PowerPC_POWER7 Processor type        False
```